# API, passing bearer token to GET HTTP URL

Tags: api, http, twitter, https, oauth

I have a [OAuth2](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/guides/bearer-tokens) (bearer token), but how do I pass it to the endpoint? More precisely, how do I include the bearer token in the URL.

Example URL:

https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=%23superbowl&result_type=recent

Example Bearer Token:

```
AAAAA5n0w5n0w5n0wMyL0ngBe4r4rT0k4n
```

How do I use my bearer token to authorize my requests?

Example Incorrect Usage:

https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=%23superbowl&result_type=recent&bearer=AAAAA5n0w5n0w5n0wMyL0ngBe4r4rT0k4n

Answer (score 31):

You can do it in two equivalent ways:

- by using the URL `access_token` parameter:

  ```
  https://base.url?access_token=f4f4994a875f461ca4d7708b9e027df4
  ```
- or by adding the `Authorization` header:

  ```
  Authorization: Bearer f4f4994a875f461ca4d7708b9e027df4
  ```

*Note*: Whether two or only one of these methods works sometimes depends on the specific implementation of the web application (including the services and libraries used to create it).

Comment: it is giving 401 unauthorized error

Comment: Hi @HarshaBiyani, did you try both methods?

Comment: 2nd is working at my end.. I wanted 1st to work

Comment: OK, @HarshaBiyani, thanks for your last comment. I added a note to my answer.

Answer (score 3):

https://YourApiUrl?access_token=0db69822-0d02-4c17-8c39-d3b818bee184

Append the valid bearer token as value to the key "access_token". This worked for me.

Comment: it is giving 401 unauthorized error

Answer (score 2):

On Postman go to:

1. Authentication tab
2. Select type: Bearer Token
3. Paste in your Token

If you want it in the URL too like you mentioned, just pass it in as parameter in the GET request.

[image: Postman bearer token screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1. `https://base.url` and set the request type.
2. Now under the url there is an Authorization tab --> click it.
3. When you in the Authorization tab select the Authorization type and fill the required token fields.

> You are using the `OAuth 2.0` but there several more `API Key / Bearer Token / ..`

4. Before sending the request Make sure to send a body if the request is waiting for a parameters.

- Body tab under the url field --> click it.
- Selected the required datatype `none / form-data / raw / ..`
- If the raw datatype was selected make sure to select the schema-type

> `Text / javascript / JSON / HTML / XML`

Here is a quick explaination video:

> https://www.screencast.com/t/E3igDLQE

Answer (score -3):

[image: example of use the authorization header in url]

FYI,

```
https://Endpointurl?Authorization=Bearer 00D2w000000kc19!AQ0AQAXCu2pbsBn4YvKuvUbNieCGmG2CVL4lqVaJruAXKZYWuAQiuxtuMiOgvGw2KQ.E4CJtkOdUw0_Q7yUzQh_3XAgwWQfd
```

Hope you understood how to pass the token

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/4FOEIGd.png                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  Trying but doesn't work. I'll just post the bearer token here.

https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/timelines/api-reference/get-statuses-user_timeline

{"token_type":"bearer","access_token":"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAHRQBAEAAAAAqMqqfNPmB6PeWXagAaTHy0ZqkCI%3DTHEuxcGlH0LT13o6g3QpcwfJBZ7tVNqIMfEsjQMK0JQELijklR"}

Comment: https://Endpointurl?Authorization=Bearer AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAHRQBAEAAAAAqMqqfNPmB6PeWXagAaTHy0ZqkCI%3DTHEuxcGlH0LT13o6g3QpcwfJBZ7tVNqIMfEsjQMK0JQELijklR

Comment: Nope: https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=superbowl&Authorization=Bearer%20AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAHRQBAEAAAAAqMqqfNPmB6PeWXagAaTHy0ZqkCI%253DTHEuxcGlH0LT13o6g3QpcwfJBZ7tVNqIMfEsjQMK0JQELijklR
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?Bearer%20AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAHRQBAEAAAAAqMqqfNPmB6PeWXagAaTHy0ZqkCI%253DTHEuxcGlH0LT13o6g3QpcwfJBZ7tVNqIMfEsjQMK0JQELijklR

Comment: the code will expire every 10 minutes.. so pass updated code and check