# How to pass bearer access_token in URL for Get request to ABP API

Tags: abp

I'm using ABP vNext v3.3, and had no problem to call the Api when passing Bearer access_code in request Header.

However, I want to put the the access_code within URL directly as a link, then user can perform the same action by just clicking the link.
Does anybody know whether it's possible and how to pass the query string? I tried:

*https://endpoint?access_code=[my access code]*

*https://endpoint?Authorization=Bearer+[my access code]*

Unfortunately there's no joy.
Thanks

Comment: It's called an access_token (not access_code) See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59356703/api-passing-bearer-token-to-get-http-url

Comment: @Arie Thanks, but it does not work.
I found very useful content from this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21496536/10350621, and it works fine now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the info. I got from https://stackoverflow.com/a/21496536/10350621, below is my implementation which works fine.

In *MyProjectName*HttpApiHostModule.cs, add JwtBearerEvents for getting token from either header or QueryString:

```cs
private void ConfigureAuthentication(ServiceConfigurationContext context, IConfiguration configuration)
{
    context.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            options.Authority = configuration["AuthServer:Authority"];
            options.RequireHttpsMetadata = Convert.ToBoolean(configuration["AuthServer:RequireHttpsMetadata"]);
            options.Audience = "MySystemName";
            options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents()
            {                        
                OnMessageReceived = c =>
                {
                    string authorization = c.Request.Headers["Authorization"];

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(authorization) && authorization.StartsWith("Bearer ", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                    {
                        c.Token = authorization.Substring("Bearer ".Length).Trim();
                    }
                    // If no authorization header found, then check access_token from QueryString
                    else
                    {
                        var accessToken = c.Request.Query["access_token"];
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken))
                        {
                            c.Token = accessToken;
                        }
                    }

                    // If no token found, no further work possible
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.Token))
                    {
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    }

                    c.NoResult();
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                }
            };
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass toke when call api in header

Authorization : Bearer + code

use this link to get token

https://localhost:44319/connect/token

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/teqvg.png)

Comment: Indeed, my question was not about how to get token, instead I wanted to pass got token to API through URL, anyway I figured it out. thanks.